# Can I block receiving iOS Push Notifications during specified hours (night time) programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

my client wants to have an UISwitch control in Settings view in his app which is: 'Disable Notifications during night time'. He would like pushes that his API will be sending to mobile to be ignored if this option is turned on and it's a night time. Is this possible? I know that I can register and unregister for remote notifications, but this requires an App to be turned on. Is it possible to have it working like he wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to have a configuration in the back-end. Notifications are sent from a server, and only handled in the app. There is no way, besides unregistering the phone from receiving notifications, to have the phone deny a notification in a certain time frame.

The user can set a time preference in the app, send it to the server, and have the server do a check so it only sends the notification to the user in the preferred time period.

Check out this 3rd party repo to send your push notifications and just write in your own check before pushing the notification.

https://github.com/nomad/houston

Comment: This is what I thought. I just wanted to be sure that his API team needs to include such feature and cannot be done on my side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can register or unregister for push notifications, i hope in your code switch you can make something like this:

```
let application = UIApplication.shared
//Didnt receive push
application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()

//Receive push
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

and if your client wants make this in Backend you can put a value on some database table with field receive:Bool, and the backend just take all the receive == true to send push notification on this devices

Comment: I understand that, but a client don't want this to be made on Backend side. He'd like a phone to control it locally.

Comment: If you want to take control from your phone usage the code on the UISwitch action